Считать целое число и вывести его и соседние числа
Нужен код, который считывает и выводит целое число, а потом на экран выводятся предыдущее и следующее целые числа с пояснительным текстом
0 = int(input())

print('Следующее за числом', 0, 'число:', 0 + 1)
print('Для числа', 0, 'предыдущее число:', 0 - 1)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

у вас рабочий код, просто замените имя переменной "0" на имя допустимое в питоне, например, на var

number = int(input())

print('Следующее за числом', number, 'число:', number + 1)
print('Для числа', number, 'предыдущее число:', number - 1)

В переменной number сохранится целое число введенное пользователем, значит, number + 1 будет следующим и number - 1 предыдущим целым числом.
Вашей ошибкой было то, что имя переменной должно начинаться с буквы или знака подчеркивания (_), а вы использовали число (0).
